# Split query or use original query to search in vector database?

Tags: embedding, information-retrieval

For example I have a query "chinese resturant in new york"

I want more different words to appear in the query result, the more the better

1. Split query ["chinese", "resturant", "new york"], get their embeddings, 3 in total, and write algorithms to achieve similiar effect of `bool should` query like below in es.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "content": {
                            "query": "chinese"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "content": {
                            "query": "resturant"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "content": {
                            "query": "new york"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": "2<70%"
        }
    },
    "size": 20
}
```

2. Just use original string "chinese resturant in new york", get its embedding, search in vector database

which is better ?